# Solspace Freeform not updating, mySQL error?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, mysql

I'm getting database errors when trying update Freeform.

I think I've narrowed it down to one specific mySQL statement, but I don't know enough about mySQL to know what's wrong, I just know that this section from `db.freeform.sql` causes a syntax error at line 4:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_fields` (
    `field_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `field_name`                    varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `field_label`                   varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `field_type`                    varchar(50)         NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
    `settings`                      text,
    `author_id`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_date`                    int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `edit_date`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `required`                      char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `submissions_page`              char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `moderation_page`               char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `composer_use`                  char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `field_description`             text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`field_id`),
    KEY                             (`field_name`),
    KEY                             (`site_id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;
```

Can anyone spot the issue?

Update: for what it's worth, I just tried to install the latest Freeform for the first time on a different EE installation and got the same error.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with that. In fact, when I run the above in an empty database it works without any errors. What error are you getting specifically?

Comment: Please provide the version of Freeform that you are using, as well as the contents of the actual error that you are seeing.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, just downloaded today. The error was as follows: `Table 'expressionengine_201207.exp_freeform_multipage_hashes' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps there was a bad character in my version of the Freeform files. I was able to copy and paste the statement from above and run it successfully, but copy and pasting from the file itself throws an error.

Anyway — after running all the statements in `db.freeform.sql` individually, all seems well now, thanks for looking.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to run each of the statements individually in the other EE install as well before I could get the installation to work.